# Django: two sessions in the same browser

Tags: python, django, django-sessions

I have a Django webapp that allows users to collaborate. Each user is given a link with a unique code they click to go to my site. On the first page visit, I store this unique code in `request.session`, and then on subsequent page visits I retrieve it to identify the user's record in the DB. I also store various other stuff about the user and their session in `request.session`.

I would like to allow two sessions to occur in different windows/tabs of the same browser. This is to make testing easier. My colleagues spend a lot of time testing multiple users using the site simultaneously. So far I have been instructing them to use different browsers or different browser profiles, so that the session cookie is not shared. But they always forget this instruction (or do it wrong) and end up confused when the app doesn't work as expected.

My idea is to put the user's unique code (called `user_id`) in each URL, and then subdivide `request.session` into multiple dictionaries, so my class-based view would have this:

```
def dispatch(...):
    user_id = kwargs['user_id']
    self.request_session = self.request.session[user_id]
```

Then use this variable `self.request_session` as I usually would:

```
    self.request_session['time_started'] = now
    ...
```

And then before returning my response, assign it back:

```
    self.request.session[user_id] = self.request_session
```

I think this should be fine, since own code would keep the two sessions isolated in 2 separate dictionaries, but maybe it would break down if Django (or even a 3rd party app) stores something in request.session. Wondering if anyone has a recommendation for another way to handle this.

Comment: I agree with @bignose that using the 'private browsing' feature is the right way to solve your testing problem. And, if you still want to go with the hack you are describing, wouldnt it be more appropriately implemented as middleware rather than as part of a particular view?

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers (e.g. Firefox, Chromium, Brave, …) have the ability to open a page without reference to existing history, cookies, etc.

- In Firefox this is termed “[Private Browsing](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/private-browsing-use-firefox-without-history)”; you open a “Private Window”.
- In Brave this is termed a “Private Tab”.
- In Chromium this is termed “[Incognito Mode](https://www.chromium.org/user-experience/incognito)”.

By using any of these, you can make a new “session” that will not present as any other logged-in session. This should allow you to have an arbitrary number of sessions at once.